# Angularjs - Unwanted characters in url (http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2Famovie)

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I generated a project with `yeoman`. Routing has been going fine. I usually have urls of the form `http://localhost:9000/#/movies` and the routing has been working.

Suddenly, my urls have changed to `http://localhost:9000/#!/`. Notice the `!`.
As a result, the movies and all other urls transforms to `http://localhost:9000/#!/#%2Famovie` and routing no longer works.

*bower.json*

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "bootstrap-star-rating": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
     },
    "appPath": "app",
    "moduleName": "clientApp"
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
        "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
        "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
        "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
        "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
        "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
        "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
        "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
        "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
        "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
        "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
        "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
        "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
        "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
  "test": "karma start test\\karma.conf.js"
},
"dependencies": {
     "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.4"
 }
 }
```

*app.js*

```
angular
.module('clientApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    contorllerAs: 'ctrl'
  })
  .when('/series',{
    templateUrl: 'views/series.html',
    controller: 'SeriesController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  })
 ...etc..
```

*links*

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-11 vcenter">
    <h4>New Tv shows</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"><a href="#/series">show all</a></div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Any help fixing this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide your route code and links.

Comment: something related to hashbang urls, html5 mode

Comment: just a *guess*, bower may have updated angular to 1.6, and you are likely affected by this change: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52